# Кодировка в DENWER под Win7

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

Первый раз с такой проблемой сталкиваюсь.

Кодировка на сайте:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Кодировка таблицы в базе:

```
cp1251_general_ci
```

Форма отправляет кириллицу, а в базе сохраняются вопросики. В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай попробуйте еще задать кодировку соединения mysql.

Comment: Соединение происходит таким образом:

    $db = new MySQL(true, $DBNAME, $DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS, "CP1251");

Comment: Перестрахуйся: вместо `http-equiv` сделай

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251', true, 200);

Comment: не используйте расширение mysql, не используйте 8ми битные кодировки. посмотрите какой год на календаре.

Answer (score 2):

Вставьте код после подключения к БД:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
mysql_set_charset("cp1251")
```

Comment: Мой mysql класс это уже делает. Проблема не в этом.

Comment: Проверьте php.ini в самом денвере. Параметр default_charset

Comment: Закомментировано...

Comment: Я когда-то долго мучился с этим `SET NAMES`. У меня был указан тип сравнения вместо кодировки:

    mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8_general_ci"');

вместо

    mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');

проверь :)

Еще можно проверить, не вылетают ли эти запросы с ошибкой, мало ли.

Comment: Удалите ; перед строчкой default_charset. Еще в \usr\local\mysql-5.5\my.ini посмотрите default-character-set, character-set-server и init-connect

Comment: Вообще никак не влияют эти настройки. Как были вопросики, так и остались